# filemaker relationships not displaying

Tags: filemaker

I import races into Excel but it has grown to a large spreadsheet and has its limitations.

I have successfully imported a small test database of results.

So far I have the form in the database with the tables and relationships below but when I try to make a layout to view the form I get the horse name and 1 line of form, when I scroll down the same horse displays again with it's next run.
I think it's because I have failed to fill the foreign keys in the `horse_Race` table, or got the relationships wrong.

I also want to add a Today's runners table but am not sure how to relate it to the existing tables Is it possible to achieve these aims in filemaker or am I barking up the wrong tree. I am at an Impasse but I'm sure it's to do with the relationships somewhere?

Tables as follows:

- ***> -Course:-***

  pk_Course_ID, Course,
- ***Horse:-***

  pk_Horse_ID,Horse
- ***Races:-***

pk_Race_ID,Course,Rdate,Rtime,Going,Age,Furs,Class,Ran,

**- ***Horse_Race;-**

pk_Run_ID,fk_Course_ID,fk_Horse_ID,fk_Races_ID,Course,RDate,Rtime,Going,Age,Furs,Class,Ran,Pos,Drw,TBtn,Horse,Wgt,MARK,GRD,WA,AA,BHB,BHBAdj,RATING,PPL

Relationships from primary key in each table to foreign keys in Horse_race table.
My aims are as follows.

1. To view EACH individual horse and its FORM in date order latest run at the top

AJCook (IRE)

DATE         CRSE   Going   Furs    Class   Ran     Pos     Drw     TBtn    Wgt
MARK    GRD     RATING

31-Jul-13   REDC    GD  6         6     11  11  1   20.8    133     65  63                      -1

08-Jul-13   RIPO    GF  6         6     11  7   3   8.25    133     65  65  41

21-Jun-13   REDC    GF  5         5     5   1   4   0.02    133     60  56  54

28-May-13   REDC    GF  6         5     13  5   6   5.35    124     61  70  35

06-May-13   BEVE    GF  5         5     12  8   13  6.15    125     65  73  40

1. To add a todays runners table with races and runners from each of the days races that would loop through each horse and search the database to display the horses and their last 3 ratings latest on the right plus the TOP 9 RATINGS FROM THE LAST 3 RATINGS IN ORDER like so:-
   HORSE   R1  R2  R3          HORSE   RATE
   A J Cook (IRE)  54  41  -1          Abadejo     57
   Aaranyow (IRE)  45  36  48          Abadejo     56
   Aarti (IRE)     44  43  40          A J Cook (IRE)  54
   Aazif (IRE)     46  43  23          Abadejo     54
   Abadejo     56  54  57          Aaranyow (IRE)  48

How do I add the todays runners table which has the following data
Date Time,Course,Furs,HorseNo Horse
How will it be related to the tables I already have? Many thanks

Davey H

Answer (score 0):

FileMaker can easily do this. But I am a bit confused with your blocks of text up there, can you format them a little better so that I can see what tables hold which fields please?

Comment: Thank you for your time but unfortunately despite everything being lined up correctly when I edit this post everything goes awry when I resave the post. Being a newbie I am unable to figure out why.Pity there is no option for attachments.